# Change HTML SELECT OPTIONs using a json object in FBJS

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs

I have a html select input with a default set of options (it has an ID). I also have a json object that looks like

`var replacement_options = {'value 1':'display 1', 'value 2':'display 2' ....`

How would I replace the options in the select with the values and displays from the json object using Facebook JS? (FBJS)

Comment: I wish I could give you more upvotes - I'm nearly fbjs (and plain old js) illiterate and I've been banging my head against this for days now.

Comment: Thanks, fbjs is a little frustrating, because many of simple answers that are all over the internet don't work out well. For the next project I may just iframe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After piecing some stuff together, I was able to create a function to do this.

```
    //accepts a object for options {value1:display1, value2:display2...
    function updateSelectOptionsWithJSON(element_id, options, first_display, first_value)
    {
            var choiceList = document.getElementById(element_id);
            for(var count = choiceList.getOptions().length - 1; count > -1; count--)
            {
                    var node = choiceList.getOptions()[count];
                    choiceList.removeChild(node);
            }
            //you can remove these next 4 lines and the last two parameters of this function
            //if you just want options to come from the secton parameter
            var node =  document.createElement('option');
            node.setTextValue(first_display);
            node.setValue(first_value);
            choiceList.appendChild(node);

            for(key in options)
            {
                    var node =  document.createElement('option');
                    node.setTextValue(options[key]);
                    node.setValue(key);
                    choiceList.appendChild(node);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try playing with the FBJS function `selectNode.removeChild` described in the FBJS wiki entry [FBJS](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS#Manipulating_Objects)

you will also need to use

```
var option = document.createElement('option');
selectNode.appendChild(option);
```

to create the option nodes inside the select node